# How can I access Groovy globals from inside a class?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, global-variables

We have a script in our Jenkins shared pipeline code which works along these lines, in `src/Utils.groovy`:

```
boolean isBuildNumberEven() {
    int number = env.BUILD_NUMBER as int
    (number % 2) == 0
}
```

This script is then used like this from one of the scripts in `vars/`

```
Utils utils = new Utils()
if (utils.isBuildNumberEven()) {
    // Do something differently
}
```

The key point is that `env` apparently can be used with no problem.

Now  I want to clean up the code and explicitly declare the class, so I change `src/Utils.groovy` like so:

```
class Utils {
    boolean isBuildNumberEven() {
        int number = env.BUILD_NUMBER as int
        (number % 2) == 0
    }
}
```

Now, I get an error about `env` being accessed as a global while it is not a global.

The Groovy compiler itself obviously knows how to convert a script with no class into a class, but I haven't quite figured out how to do it myself.

Is there a trick to allow me to access those global variables from the class, other than the obvious one of passing them all in via the constructor? Is there some global class somewhere which contains them all perhaps?

(Note that although I have used `env` for this example, it is not the only one I need to access. So yes, I already converted these to use `System.getenv`, but then immediately hit some other variable we were using. So there's no easy way out.)

Comment: Could you explain the goal explicitly declaring the class?

Comment: @daggett we've decided that bare methods at the file top-level is bad code style so we're trying to clean that up. (It was mentioned in the question as well.)

Comment: actually when you are creating a `/vars/groovy` file - you are like creating a class. just imagine that you could omit the `class Util{` declaration. so, truthfully i can't imagine how it could help to make your code cleaner.  however you could pass `this` from the workflow into your class constructor and use it like this: `workflow.env`

Comment: but i'd use src/groovy to create some atomic jenkins independent classes - like helpers that are easy to use. vars/groovy - reusable scripted steps that are using other steps and helpers. create context class (or use simple map) with all variables required for your flow and just pass it between your groovy vars/classes.

Comment: @daggett this file is in `src/`, not in `vars/`. That was also stated in the first line of the question. :) I agree that the scripts in `vars` make more sense just having the one method. The way Jenkins actually executes those is also quite mysterious, so I wouldn't have any clue how to convert those into normal classes.